# Eclipse doesn't have "Project facets" after install of JBoss WTP adapter

Tags: eclipse, jboss-tools

I'm trying to use project facets in Eclipse but the "project facets" section under "project -> properties" is gone. I noticed this when switching to Eclipse Juno from Eclipse Indigo. I thought this was related to Juno, so I switched back to Indigo, only to find the "project facets" were gone there too.
I tried both versions as a fresh install and with a clean workspace.

Searching the web for this issue only came up with "go to 'project -> properties -> project facets'", but this simply isn't possible.

**UPDATE:**

I managed to break it down. The facet related stuff disappears after I installed the "JBossAS Tools" package from the JBoss update site (http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/juno/).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install Eclipse Juno (4.2.0)
2. Install project facets from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno

   1. Under "Modeling": "EMF Facet SDK (Incubation)"
   2. Under "Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development": "Eclipse Faceted Project Framework"
3. After a restart see that Eclipse has possibility to create a faceted project (File -> New -> Other -> Faceted Project)
4. Install "JBossAS Tools" from http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/juno/
5. Restart, check for faceted things, aaand it's gone.

Comment: **FIX**: If right-click, properties, "Project Facets" menu does not exist:

It might happen just because when you installed the Eclipse IDE, you have no checked Web Development, I guess... So, just try:
`help - Install new software` - 
`Work with: 2020-09 - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-09 (or newer)`

In the list, check `Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development` and NEXT, NEXT.

Accept all "Review Licences".

In the status bar, you can see the message: _Installing Software xx%_.

The Project Facets menu might be working, now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the "JBossAS Tools" package from the nightly built update site. This didn't cause problems regarding project facets.

Nightly update site: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/nightly/core/trunk/

Answer (score 4):

This might depend on which install of eclipse you are using.  In any case, you can download the needed packages to get Facets working.

Facets are part of the Web Tools Platform.  If you can't find it in the package manager, you can download it here:

http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/

Comment: Using the update site "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/" I saw that "Eclipse Faceted Project Framework" and the "JDT Enablement" are installed. Any other ideas perhaps?

Comment: I had a similar problem.  Turned out I had installed the SE version of Eclipse instead of EE. >.<

Answer (score 0):

You should create your Eclipse project using `File / New / Project... / General / Faceted Project` wizard or use project's popup menu `Configure / Convert to Faceted From...`.

Comment: I have neither option. It appears I don't have any facet related option.